# Python - Pick 250 random elements from a list of 500 and save it to a new list without making it change each time i run the code

Tags: python, random

So I have an S&P500 list of tickers that contains 500 companies. I want to generate a new list with random 250 companies chosen from that list and then I want to save it to a new list. What I want to avoid is that each time I run the code, **I don't want** the program to give me a new set of 250 companies.

```
import pandas as pd
import yfinance as yf
import random

sp_wiki_url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_S%26P_500_companies"
sp_wiki_df_list = pd.read_html(sp_wiki_url)
sp500_df = sp_wiki_df_list[0]
sp_tickers = list(sp500_df['Symbol'].values)

seq = [i for i in sp_tickers]
subset = random.seed().sample(seq, 250)
```

This code here will generate a list of 250 companies but it will change each time I run the code, any way to prevent this?

Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you run it once and store the result, e.g. in a structured file like .JSON?

Comment: That's a good idea. I can run it once, save it in .json or .csv and then just import the file.

Thank you !

Comment: As long as you get the list from Wikipedia, you can't even guarantee that the 500-list starts with the same companies.

Comment: You can pass an `int` to `seed`, e.g. `random.seed(0)`.

Answer (score 0):

You should force the state of the generator, using `random.seed`, **just before** asking for your sample.

```
$ python3
Python 3.9.6 (default, Jun 29 2021, 00:00:00)
>>>
>>> import  random
>>>
>>> random.seed(42)
>>> random.sample(range(30), 10)
[20, 3, 0, 23, 8, 7, 24, 4, 28, 17]
>>> 
>>> random.sample(range(30), 10)
[2, 18, 13, 1, 0, 29, 6, 7, 16, 19]
>>> 
>>> random.seed(42)
>>> random.sample(range(30), 10)
[20, 3, 0, 23, 8, 7, 24, 4, 28, 17]
>>>
```

Comment: as Thomas noted above, setting the RNG state doesn't help if the wikipedia page changes.  OP should be saving the output somewhere then loading it back in when ever they want the sample to "stay the same"

Comment: @SamMason - well yes you're right. If the list happened to include *Bernie Madoff Inc.* and this is now gone, there is nothing Python can do. A possibility is to test every time whether the 500-long list has changed, and if so, whether the old list still makes any sense.

Comment: or just save the relevant 250 rows of the dataframe...